# Visual Studio colour scheme, how to find out which colour scheme this is

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface, ide

I am trying to find a specific colour scheme for Visual Studio Code (it's the same colour scheme that an instructor uses in an online course). I have a screenshot of it (attached). I find this colour scheme to be particularly good for my eyes so I really want to find which one it is. How to find out which one it is? Thanks
[This is the Visual Studio colour scheme I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq3xT.png)

Comment: Looks like this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Mik.atomvs-one-dark-theme

Comment: I don't think this is it, but it does look similar to [One Monokai VS Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=azemoh.onemonokai). I personally prefer [OneDarkPro](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adrianwilczynski.one-dark-pro) which is also similar.

Comment: Does the comments resovle your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, it's not any of those, but I may be able to use something like that for my eyes. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found that the palette I was looking for was very similar to some Monodevelop colors, I actually ended up building a new theme for Visual Studio Code based on that, and published it as an extension for Visual Studio Code, called it MonoDevKai since it's supposed to be a mix between Monodevelop and dark versions of Monokai. As of writing this, it's not very customized but I plan to customize it a bit more in the future. You can find the theme as an extension in the Visual Studio Code marketplace here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Heracles.monodevkai
or install it directly from Visual Studio Code extensions panel.
Thanks for the replies

Comment: Hi spacedar, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)